# How to use liveWallpaper as your background image

Tags: android

I have created a simple app. Now I want to have a live wallpaper as a background image in my App. So how that can be done? Is there any example code related using live wallpaper as a background in our app. If anyone knows please help me to solve this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
WallpaperManager.getInstance(class.this).setResource("your image path/from drawable");
```

Comment: Is there aything we have to declare in androidManifestFile.xml

Comment: One more question?How can i use these live wallPaper as Background in my app.

Comment: permittion for setbackground.

Comment: @Siten: Is a live wallpaper simply an .xml file in the res/drawable folder or is it more than that? Shouldn't there be a bitmap file somewhere in the application file directory that the .xml file references?